# Why is my code clobbering the current line?

Tags: bash, append

I'm trying to build a csv of countries a list of ipv4 addresses come from.
I keep clobbering the IP in the output file;

```
#!/bin/bash
cat ipv4list.txt | while read ip ;do
  echo -n "$ip", >> outputfile
  whois -r "$ip">temp.txt
  cat temp.txt | grep -i country >> outputfile
done
```

cat ipv4list.txt

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

What I'd like is outputfile to read;

```
1.1.1.1,country:    AU
2.2.2.2,country:    US
```

but I'm getting outputfile as follows;

```
,country:    AU
,country:    US
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Trying to append code in the comments.  Not my day.  input is 1.1.1.1 followed by 2.2.2.2 on next line.  Output needs to be 1.1.1.1,country:  AU before starting next line.   What I'm actually getting as output is ,country:  AU

Comment: Did you try to verify the `outputfile` using `xxd` or `od -cx`? Maybe `whois` produece a carriage return in its output. Also, you do not write the ip address to the output file, but the literal string `ip`. Finally, your last two lines can be simplified to `whois -r $ip|grep -i country >>outputfile`.

Comment: Ah thx.  Awesome.  xxd shows the IP is in there after all.  Cant see it with cat.  Looking at the hex there are newlines in there, and 0x0a which might be the culprit.
Typo in recreating the code above.  It does have a $ in my code.  Good pick up though.  I'll edit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The echo statement need the refer to he ip variable:

```
echo -n "$ip", >> outputfile
```

Also, the clobbering indicate they input file may use window new lines (\r\n).  Check the output file with editor, or hexdump

Comment: Thanks.  Hex shows the IP is in there after all.  Need to filter out some weird hex characters.

Answer (score 0):

Going a bit outside the box, here.  Please be kind, guys.

```
pop.ed:-

1d
wq

whois.sh:-

#!/bin/sh -x

init() {
    cp ipv4list ipv4stack
}

next() {
    [[ -s ipv4stack ]] && main
}

main() {
    ip=$(echo "1p" | ed -s ipv4stack.txt)
    wic=$(whois -r "${ip}")
    echo "${ip},${wic}" >> outputfile
    ed -s ipv4stack.txt < pop.ed
    next
}

init
next
```

Ed apparently isn't installed by default in most distributions these days either, sadly; so you may need to install it if you want to use this.